# I am trying to retrieve the data and displaying in a list view but it is showing an error

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to retrieve the data and displaying in a list view but it is showing an error.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building expanse(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _expanseState#6acc3):
The getter 'data' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: data
```

The relevant error-causing widget was:

```
  expanse file:///C:/Users/sindh/AndroidStudioProjects/final_project/lib/Dashboard.dart:261:91
```

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

```
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      _expanseState.build (package:hrms_project/Expenses/expencedashboard.dart:258:39)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4612:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4495:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4667:11)

I/flutter (16460): 200
E/flutter (16460): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'histories' was called on null.
E/flutter (16460): Receiver: null
E/flutter (16460): Tried calling: histories
E/flutter (16460): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter (16460): #1      _expanseState.initState.<anonymous closure> (package:hrms_project/Expenses/expencedashboard.dart:24:27)
E/flutter (16460): #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter (16460): #3      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
E/flutter (16460): #4      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:152:18)
E/flutter (16460): #5      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:704:45)
E/flutter (16460): #6      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:733:32)
E/flutter (16460): #7      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:539:5)
E/flutter (16460): #8      _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:254:13)
E/flutter (16460): #9      Services.getExpense (package:hrms_project/Api.dart)
E/flutter (16460): <asynchronous suspension>
```

This is json decode code

```
 import 'dart:convert';
    Expense expenseFromJson(String str) => Expense.fromJson(json.decode(str));
    String expenseToJson(Expense data) => json.encode(data.toJson());
    
    class Expense {
      Expense({
        this.success,
        this.statusCode,
        this.data,
        this.message,
      });
    
      bool success;
      int statusCode;
      Data data;
      String message;
    
      factory Expense.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Expense(
        success: json["success"],
        statusCode: json["statusCode"],
        data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
        message: json["message"],
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "statusCode": statusCode,
        "data": data.toJson(),
        "message": message,
      };
    }
    
    class Data {
      Data({
        this.histories,
      });
    
      List<History> histories;
    
      factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
        histories: List<History>.from(json["histories"].map((x) => History.fromJson(x))),
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "histories": List<dynamic>.from(histories.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
    }
    
    class History {
      History({
        this.id,
        this.employeeId,
        this.reference,
        this.categoryId,
        this.currencyId,
        this.amount,
        this.date,
        this.merchant,
        this.description,
        this.attachments,
        this.companyId,
        this.status,
    
      });
    
      int id;
      EmployeeId employeeId;
      Reference reference;
      String categoryId;
      String currencyId;
      String amount;
      Date date;
      String merchant;
      String description;
      String attachments;
      CompanyId companyId;
      String status;
    
    
      factory History.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => History(
        id: json["id"],
        employeeId: employeeIdValues.map[json["employee_id"]],
        reference: referenceValues.map[json["reference"]],
        categoryId: json["category_id"],
        currencyId: json["currency_id"],
        amount: json["amount"],
        date: dateValues.map[json["date"]],
        merchant: json["merchant"],
        description: json["description"],
        attachments: json["attachments"],
        companyId: companyIdValues.map[json["company_id"]],
        status: json["status"],
    
    
      );
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "employee_id": employeeIdValues.reverse[employeeId],
        "reference": referenceValues.reverse[reference],
        "category_id": categoryId,
        "currency_id": currencyId,
        "amount": amount,
        "date": dateValues.reverse[date],
        "merchant": merchant,
        "description": description,
        "attachments": attachments,
        "company_id": companyIdValues.reverse[companyId],
        "status": status,
    
      };
    }
    
    enum CompanyId { ECS_934284 }
    
    final companyIdValues = EnumValues({
      "ECS-934284": CompanyId.ECS_934284
    });
    
    enum Date { THE_00000000 }
    
    final dateValues = EnumValues({
      "0000-00-00": Date.THE_00000000
    });
    
    enum EmployeeId { EMPMOB_006 }
    
    final employeeIdValues = EnumValues({
      "EMPMOB-006": EmployeeId.EMPMOB_006
    });
    
    enum Reference { USER }
    
    final referenceValues = EnumValues({
      "user": Reference.USER
    });
    class EnumValues<T> {
      Map<String, T> map;
      Map<T, String> reverseMap;
    
      EnumValues(this.map);
    
      Map<T, String> get reverse {
        if (reverseMap == null) {
          reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
        }
        return reverseMap;
      }
    }
```

This is the API code

```
    class Services {
      static const String url = 'basic url';
    
      static Future <Expense> getExpense() async {
    
          final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('basic url'));
          print(response.statusCode);
          if(200 == response.statusCode){
            final Expense = expenseFromJson(response.body);
            return Expense;
          }else{
            return Expense();
          }
    
      }
    }
```

This is the UI

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_session/flutter_session.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:hrms_project/Api.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


class getdata {
  String category;
  String date;
  String merchant;
  String reference;
  String description;
  String currencytype;
  String amount;
  String tax;

  getdata({
    @required this.category,
    @required this.date,
    @required this.merchant,
    @required this.reference,
    @required this.description,
    @required this.currencytype,
    @required this.amount,
    @required this.tax,

  });
}



class editpage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _editpageState createState() => _editpageState();
}




class _editpageState extends State<editpage> {

  String SelectDate="Click and select date";
  String ctype = "SGD";
  String doller = "1";

  String _category;
  List Category = [
    'Allowance',
    'Dental Claim',
    'Fuel Expense',
    'Home base-Taxi/Car RENTAL',
    'Home base -mileage',
    'IT and Internet Expense',
    'Meals and Entertainment',
    'Medical Claim',
    'Office Supplies',
    'Other Expense',
    'Transport Claims',
    'Travel-Airline',
    'Travel-Overseas Allowance',
    'Travel Claim',
  ];

  String currencychoose;
  List listcurrency = [
    'SGD', 'CNY', 'MYR', 'THB', 'TWD', 'USD', 'VND', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'IDR', 'JPY',
  ];

  String taxchoose;
  List listTax = [
    'GST 0% (0%)',
    'GST 7% (7%)',
    'Service Charge 10% (10%)  ',
  ];

  String Report;
  List report = [
    "PO-0049-Dominic's",
    "PO-0048-April Japan Trip Project",
    "PO-0045-Project A March 2021",
    "PO-0044-Local Transport-SG",
    "PO-0037-Nov2020 Claims",
  ];

  var claimsController = new TextEditingController();
  var currencyController = new TextEditingController();
  var taxController = new TextEditingController();
  var reporttypeController = new TextEditingController();
  var merchantController = new TextEditingController();
  var selectdateController = new TextEditingController();
  var referenceController = new TextEditingController();
  var descriptionController = new TextEditingController();
  var amountController = new TextEditingController();

  void getItemNavigate(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context);

    print("Merchant Name is : ${merchantController.text}");
    print("Select Date : ${selectdateController.text}");
    print("Reference Code is : ${referenceController.text}");
    print("Description is : ${descriptionController.text}");
    print("Claims is: ${claimsController.text}");
    print("Select Tax : ${taxController.text}");
    print(" Amount : ${currencyController.text} ${amountController.text}");
    print("Currency Value: ${currencyController.text}");
    print("Report: ${reporttypeController.text}");
  }

  DateTime date = DateTime.now();

  Future DatePicker(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: date,
      firstDate: new DateTime(DateTime
          .now()
          .year - 50),
      lastDate: new DateTime(DateTime
          .now()
          .year + 50),
    );
    if (picked != null && picked != date) {
      setState(() {
        date = picked;
        print(date.toString());
        selectdateController.text=DateFormat.yMMMd().format(date).toString();
        SelectDate =DateFormat.yMMMd().format(date).toString();
      });
    }
  }

  File _pickedImage;

  void _pickImageCamera() async{
    final picker= await ImagePicker();
    final pickedImage= await picker.getImage(source:ImageSource.camera);
    final pickedImageFile =File(pickedImage.path);
    setState((){
      _pickedImage =pickedImageFile;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void _pickImageGallery() async{
    final picker= await ImagePicker();
    final pickedImage= await picker.getImage(source:ImageSource.gallery);
    final pickedImageFile = File(pickedImage.path);
    setState((){
      _pickedImage =pickedImageFile;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void _Remove(){
    setState((){
      _pickedImage= null;
    });
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height * 0.1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[300],
        leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Edit Expense', style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          color:Colors.grey[200],
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .width,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0,left: 10,right: 10),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            color:Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('Category', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Colors.grey[800],)),
                      SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButton(
                              hint: Text('Select Category'),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.blue,),
                              iconSize: 30,
                              value: _category,
                              onChanged: (newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _category = newValue;
                                  claimsController.text=_category;
                                });
                              },
                              items: Category.map((valueItem) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: valueItem,
                                  child: Text(valueItem),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
                Radius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text("${SelectDate}", style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 17, color: Colors.grey[600]),),
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,color: Colors.blueAccent,size:30),
                            onTap: () {
                              DatePicker(context);
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                             
                            Container(
                              width: 180,
                              height: 50,
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: amountController,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Enter Amount",
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  ),
                                ),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
               
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 70,
                              height: 48,
                              color: Colors.grey[100],
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('1 ${ctype} =',style:TextStyle(fontSize:16.0,color:Colors.black,)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 140,
                              height: 48,
                              color: Colors.grey[300],
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('${doller}',style:TextStyle(fontSize:16.0,color:Colors.black,)),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 47,
                              height: 48,
                              color: Colors.grey[100],
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text('SGD'),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('Tax', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Colors.grey[800],)),
                      SizedBox(height: 6.0),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButton(
                              hint: Text('Please select the Tax'),
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.blue,),
                              iconSize: 30,
                              value: taxchoose,
                              onChanged: (newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  taxchoose = newValue;
                                  taxController.text=taxchoose;
                                });
                              },
                              items: listTax.map((valueItem) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: valueItem,
                                  child: Text(valueItem),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )      
                      Container(
                        margin:EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text('Click and select files-->',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,color:Colors.red),),
                            RawMaterialButton(
                              elevation: 6.0,
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.add_a_photo, size: 40, color: Colors.blue,),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              shape: CircleBorder(),
                              onPressed: () {
                                showDialog(context: context,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                      return AlertDialog(
                                        title: Text('Choose option', style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          color: Colors.pinkAccent,),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        ),
                                        content: SingleChildScrollView(
                                          child: ListBody(
                                            children: [
                                              InkWell(
                                                onTap:_pickImageCamera,
                                                splashColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
                                                child: Row(
                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                                      .center,
                                                 
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                              InkWell(
                                                onTap:_pickImageGallery,
                                                splashColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
                                                child: Row(
                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                                      .center,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Padding(
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                        child: Icon(Icons.image,
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .purpleAccent,
                                                            size: 25)
                                                    ),
                                                    Text('Gallery', style: TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 18,
                                                      color: Colors.black,)),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                  height: 5
                                              ),
                                              InkWell(
                                                onTap:_Remove,
                                                splashColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
                                                child: Row(
                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                                      .center,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Padding(
                                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                      child: Icon(Icons.remove_circle,
                                                          color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                                                          size: 25),
                                                    ),
                                                    
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    });
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height:10.0),
                      Divider(height: 0.1,thickness: 1,color: Colors.grey[200],),
                      SizedBox(height:5.0),
                      FlatButton(
                        color: Colors.lightGreen,
                        shape:
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        ),
                        child:Text('Save',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,color:Colors.white),),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          var claims = claimsController.text;
                          var tax = taxController.text;
                          var reporttype = reporttypeController.text;
                          var merchant = merchantController.text;
                          var selectdate = selectdateController.text;
                          var description = descriptionController.text;
                          var amount = amountController.text;


                          var rsp = await claim(claims, amount, selectdate, merchant, tax, description, reporttype);
                          print(rsp);

                          if (rsp.containsKey('success') == true) {
                            print(rsp);
                            if (rsp['success'] == true) {


                              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                  msg: "saved",
                                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                                  gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,

                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  textColor: Colors.green,
                                  fontSize: 16.0
                              );

                            }

                            
                            }
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
return Expense.fromJson(result);
```

try changing it.

Comment: its not working, again i am getting same error.

Comment: The getter 'data' was called on null means some object gets null data to show it throws the error. so you can add null safety condition like this :-  add_data ?? "";